# In Tensorflow, I'm getting shape errors when doing data augmentation with Keras preprocessing layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, keras-layer, data-augmentation

I'm training a CNN and am applying data augmentation through Keras layers by defining:

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(factor=0.4, fill_mode="wrap"),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomTranslation(height_factor=0.2, width_factor=0.2, fill_mode="wrap"),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomContrast(factor=0.2),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomHeight(factor=0.2),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomWidth(factor=0.2)
])
```

Here are snippets of the code in question:

```
def process(x, y):
  x = DATASETS_DIR + "/" + x + ".jpg"
  x = tf.io.read_file(x)
  x = tf.image.decode_jpeg(x, channels=3)
  x = tf.image.resize(x, [299, 299])
  x = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)(x)
  
  return x, y

def process_with_augmentation(x, y):
  x, y = process(x, y)

  x = data_augmentation(x)

  return x, y

train_ds = train_ds.map(process_with_augmentation, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
validation_ds = validation_ds.map(process, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

If I comment out `x = data_augmentation(x)` in `process_with_augmentation()` the code works fine. If I don't comment out, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for '{{node sequential/random_rotation/transform/ImageProjectiveTransformV3}} = ImageProjectiveTransformV3[dtype=DT_FLOAT, fill_mode="WRAP", interpolation="BILINEAR"](rescaling/add, sequential/random_rotation/rotation_matrix/concat, sequential/random_rotation/transform/strided_slice, sequential/random_rotation/transform/fill_value)' with input shapes: [299,299,3], [299,8], [2], [].
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A keras layer expect a batch size. When you map your function on the tf.data.Dataset, the image will lack that batch dimension. You can fix that by adding a dimension before calling your keras preprocessing model :

```
def process_with_augmentation(x, y):
  x, y = process(x, y)

  x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=0) # adding the batch dimension
  x = data_augmentation(x)
  x = tf.squeeze(x, [0]) # removing the batch dimension
  return x, y
```

Another option is to call `tf.data.Dataset.batch` before calling the model, i.e :

```
train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x,y:(data_augmentation(x),y))
```

If you want to get rid of that extra dimension, you can then call `unbatch` on the augmented dataset.

---

This is not the most elegant way of solving this, though. I would suggest integrating directly your preprocessing model in your neural network, or rewriting your preprocessing logic using functions from the `tf.image` module.

Comment: When I integrated the preprocessing in the model, the performance completely tanked. Not sure why this is happening.

I tried your technique and it's not playing nice with dataset:

`The calling iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached. In order to avoid unexpected truncation of the dataset, 
the partially cached contents of the dataset will be discarded. This can happen if you have an input pipeline similar to dataset.cache().take(k).repeat(). You should use dataset.take(k).cache().repeat() instead.`

Comment: I suppose the problem is that the keras preprocessing model is using is own queuing system and that does not play nicely with your `tf.data.Dataset`. The easiest option is probably to rewrite your preprocessing logic with `tf.image`` functions.